# Why won't my app change to dark mode (Android Q) when the list preference is set?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-dark-theme

I have a listpreference within settings using the guidelines for Android Developers but the app theme does not change when the user selects either light or dark.

root_preferences:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListPreference
    android:id="@+id/list"
    app:entries="@array/theme_entries"
    app:entryValues="@array/theme_values"
    app:key="theme"
    app:title="@string/theme_title"
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

<Preference
    app:key="webpage"
    app:title="Profile"
    app:summary="View and edit your profile (opens in browser)">
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:data="https://canvas.thelatinschool.org/profile" />
</Preference>

<Preference
    android:id="@+id/notq"
    app:key="notq"
    app:title="Dark Mode"
    app:summary="Dark Mode under construction for Android Pie and below"
    >

</Preference>
```

Arrays:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<string-array name="theme_entries">
    <item>Light</item>
    <item>Dark</item>
    <item>System default</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="theme_values">
    <item>light</item>
    <item>dark</item>
    <item>default1</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

And my SettingsFragment where it is supposed to change the theme:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
        final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("theme");
        Preference preference = (Preference) findPreference("notq");
        int api = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        if (api > 28) {
            screen.removePreference(preference);
        }
        if (api < 29) {
            screen.removePreference(listPreference);
        }
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                listPreference.setValue(newValue.toString());
                theme = String.valueOf(listPreference.getEntry());
                Log.d("debug", theme);
                if (theme == "Light") {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
                if (theme == "Dark") {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                }
                if (theme == "System default") {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The log output gives the values "Light" or "Dark" but the theme itself does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I am trying to make another listpreference for a dark theme implementation for Android 9 and below, so assuming that my array values are the same what would I have to change in SettingsFragment for that to work?

Answer (score 2):

Do not compare `String`s with `==`.  Use `if theme.equals("Light")`.  In Java, `==` compares reference identity (are the two objects stored at the same memory address), whereas `String.equals` compares the value of the two `String`s as a human would expect.

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately the problem is still the same, nothing happens when the listview is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing the entry value with your entry name. It should be like this:

```
if (theme == "light") {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO);
}
if (theme == "dark") {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES);
}
if (theme == "default1") {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
}
```